How to fix wkhtmltopdf Warning: Failed to load image from Docker container?
I'm trying to run wkhtmltopdf inside a Docker container, but it fails to load images from external URLs. The command I'm using is:
wkhtmltopdf document.html output.pdf

Warning: Failed to load http://example.com/image.png (ignore)

While the HTML document converts fine, it doesn't load images from URLs like http://example.com/image.png. I can access the image URLs in the browser, and the container has internet access, but wkhtmltopdf still can't load the images.
$ curl -I http://example.com/image.png.
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: example.com

How can I fix this so that wkhtmltopdf correctly loads external images from inside the Docker container?

I think you have problem with DNS in your container. If you try curl and don't use hostname but rather IP, will it work? Can you ping 8.8.8.8 from inside container?
